# How to make "handler" lookup for "dispatcher" style function be typed correctly

Tags: typescript

Supposed I have a type like this:

```js
type TInfoGeneric<TType extends string, TValue> = {
  valueType: TType,
  value: TValue, // Correspond to valueType
}
```

To avoid repeating my self, I create a type map that list the possible `valueType` and matches `valueType` with, well, value's type.

```js
type TInfoTypeMap = {
    num: number;
    str: string;
}
```

Now, to actually create `TInfo`, I use mapped type to map all types into `TInfoGeneric` and then get only value side of it.

```js
type TAllPossibleTInfoMap = {
    [P in keyof TInfoTypeMap]: TInfoGeneric<P, TInfoTypeMap[P]>;
};

type TInfo = TAllPossibleTInfoMap[keyof TAllPossibleTInfoMap]; // TInfoGeneric<"num", number> | TInfoGeneric<"str", string>
```

Then, to define handlers for all types, I create another mapped type just for handlers.

```js
type TInfoHandler = {
    [P in keyof TInfoTypeMap]: (value: TInfoTypeMap[P]) => any
};

const handlers: TInfoHandler = {
    num: (value) => console.log(value.toString(16)),
    str: (value) => console.log(value),
}
```

And finally, to actually use the handler, I create a function like this:

```js
function handleInfo(info: TInfo) {
    handlers[info.valueType](info.value); // Error
}
```

I got this error:

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & string'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number & string'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Normally, it's understandable that `handlers[info.valueType]` may be a `((value: number) => any) | ((value: string) => any)`. However, in this case:

- If `info.valueType` is `'num'`, then we can be sure that `handlers[info.valueType]` is `(value: number) => any)` and `info.value` is `number`. Thus, `handlers[info.valueType]` can be called with `info.value`.
- If `info.valueType` is `'str'`, then we can be sure that `handlers[info.valueType]` is `(value: string) => any)` and `info.value` is `string`. Thus, `handlers[info.valueType]` can be called with `info.value`.

I'm not sure if this is Typescript limitation or not, but is it possible to write the code in this style so that it's type-checked?

Comment: Ah, another [correlated record types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) question.  I really need to open a new issue about this.  The short answer is going to be that you should use a type assertion and forget about it.

Comment: Okay I just opened [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, there's no convenient and type-safe solution for you here.  I've opened an issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) about this but I don't expect it to be addressed.

I see two main ways forward.  One is to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), since you legitimately know more than the compiler does here.  It could be like this:

```
function handleInfo(info: TInfo) {
    // assert your way out.  Not type safe but convenient!
    (handlers[info.valueType] as (x: number | string)=>any)(info.value); 
}
```

Now there's no error.  It's not type safe.  But it's convenient and doesn't change the emitted JavaScript.

---

Or you could try to walk the compiler through the cases and prove to it that all is fine.  This is complex, brittle, and has runtime effects:

```
const typeGuards: {
  [P in keyof TInfoTypeMap]: (x: TInfoTypeMap[keyof TInfoTypeMap])=>x is TInfoTypeMap[P];
} = {
    num: (x:any): x is number => typeof x === "number",
    str: (x:any): x is string => typeof x === "string"
}

function narrowTInfo<K extends keyof TAllPossibleTInfoMap>(
  x: TInfo, v: K): x is TAllPossibleTInfoMap[K] {
    return typeGuards[v](x.value);
} 

function handleInfo(info: TInfo) {
    if (narrowTInfo(info, "num")) {
        handlers[info.valueType](info.value); // okay
    } else {
        handlers[info.valueType](info.value); // okay
    }
}
```

That works but is obnoxious.  So I'd recommend an assertion.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was going to file an issue too, but I really can't explain the problem as good as you did (I'm not native English). I'll have to use the assertion method, as the actual type in my program isn't simply number & string but interfaces.