# Typescript - narrow type based on object dictionary?

Tags: typescript

See the code below, I'm selecting one of two functions to run from `dictionary` based on the `type` property in the `input` object.

However, because the result is a union function, Typescript throws an error.

Does anybody know how to work around this?

```
type typeA = {
  type: A
}

type typeB = {
  type: B
}

const dictionary = 
{
  A: function fA (input: typeA)...
  B: function fB (input: typeB)...
}

const input : typeA | typeB = XYZ;

const pickedFunc = dictionary[input.type]; // input.type === 'A' | 'B' (literal union)

pickedFunc(input) // <--- Error! "typeA | typeB" is not compatible with function of "typeof fA | typeof fB"
```

Comment: Can you fill in the function definitions and `XYZ` so that the example code is valid TypeScript?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how, the XYZ is meant the indicate an unknown piece of code (e.g. a generic input parameter). So basically any object with the property "Type" that's either A or B.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` above types, or are they supposed to be `'A'` and `'B'`? I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to do

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to select the correct function to run from the `dictionary`, based on the `type` parameter in the input.

Comment: I'm sorry; I think we'll just need more context before we can help

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/aNnyew) where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about.  That will allow people who want to help you to get to work trying to fix or work around the problem instead of first spending time and effort just trying to demonstrate the problem.  That will also improve the odds that any answer you received will have been tested first.  Good luck!

Comment: If [this](https://tsplay.dev/vWknDm) is your problem, it looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344871/how-to-make-handler-lookup-for-dispatcher-style-function-be-typed-correctly).  Let me know if that is the issue or not.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible as types are not evaluated at runtime. The typescript code has by that point become javascript without any static type checking. You could however use a type guard, you can read about this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).