# Issue with using mapped types inside map

Tags: typescript

I've tried to make a mapped type where I used set of Enums for keys and functions as values but I'm failing to get exact type when using that object.

View this as a very simplified version of my problem, I know I could make this work with if/else or switch statement but because of performance and clarity I wish to use sort of an **dictionary** as a data structure.

```
enum PossibleOperationEnum {
    MULTIPLY = 'MULTIPLY',
    LENGTH = 'LENGTH',
}

 type MultiplyOperation = {
    operation: PossibleOperationEnum.MULTIPLY;
    element: number;
};

 type StringLengthOperation = {
    operation: PossibleOperationEnum.LENGTH;
    element: string;
};

type AllOperations = MultiplyOperation | StringLengthOperation;

type ModificationFunction<T> = (
    modification: Extract<AllOperations, { operation: T }>,
) => any;

// Simplified version (in the original I have a lot more keys/functions)
const config: { [k in PossibleOperationEnum]: ModificationFunction<k> } = {
    LENGTH: (mod) => mod.element.length,
    MULTIPLY: (mod) => mod.element * 2
};

const content: AllOperations[] = [
    {
        operation: PossibleOperationEnum.MULTIPLY,
        element: 1,
    },
    {
        operation: PossibleOperationEnum.LENGTH,
        element: "test"
    },
]


const contentList = content.map((mod) => {
    return config[mod.operation](mod); // this is evaluating to never even tho this code works perfectly fine in practice.
})
```

Also typescript playground link: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACg9gZwQSwEYBtgHkAOwBOAhgC7JwgCi40A3gFBSNQCyAqgDIAqAkjOwJpQAvFADkbLrwGiANAybsKAOQDinABLCxi1Rtl0AvnQbEAnnhZh0pHOlO4CJMiC30mUOHiKlyALliIKBjYXk7kVJAAdBI8fPwA3PKMwJgQoMT%201KgEiQaJJubAUADKxPjIIADm7KCVxAAWDt7OrkkeoT4g-vBIaJhNYZTUkTpq6onuKcBpIBlQCGUVlbn5ZhYAgujoA50IWsxWNnY7LQA%20JYtVNVUNJ%20SrhSxwACbIAGbIAMaDAGJgIJ9OgAeTgAPi0AAo2hAXu8voN-BQAB5lQiAoGbbYdZwIGRQGjtRydfycKAGUFyACUwnBhBApnyAHpGSVkBBbHDgM8oAA3AgochQCEVKANIpwcqVCqEdBQbhQeqEPlQQhQdBwYhQGH4IoAa2ApgQjLe-0BOMpdE%205AWUCtIA%20lX8BIA2rqoCKekF%20tjwtQALr%20Ziwj7fTp-AHA3XggytdyjDT%20CEw57UoTg5ORKYzYiRTA3epydwxKT8RPJ1Ppl6Z1LpKAAKigACZDPk7Ta7cR0v5MXcQAhnX6tM62m53ExPETnN1An0QpPfVFi3FC2PkjXZv4AIwrxgGHf4truCfNPwBXrBXsRCAjZRjfeTddzABEnYWT7ae7ofuMlutmo76TsMgNoiABsyRBAhA4BCSYvBWB7uDqxBgPgLh2g6zoZsegx%20rBKbxFAzKivUwHunswA8jKYBOFUopwFAIAUQQUBMS4DT0Q0pFWs8RQAO4SrqexeG8wCAnYUAfIx7ouDgRBmp8wCRIYFpAA)

Comment: This is another instance of the lack of support for what I call "correlated union types"; see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the [linked q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55344871/2887218).   For your code here I'd say just make sure you're doing it right and then [use a type assertion to silence the warning](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8lkN).  Otherwise you can only guarantee type safety with redundant code which you don't want to have.